# Matrix rain change text in the middle of animation

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've just get into swift ui and having trouble with my first ever Swift project. I want to make a rain of quotes. It's similar to matrix rain but instead showing random characters, I want to make each "drop" shows a quote. When the "drop" is finished, it will get and show a random new quote. I made it so far that the only problem is somehow, if the "drop"  will change the quote suddenly before the "drop" can finish.

[image: screen shot of the view]

Here's the code:

```
import SwiftUI


var rainSize = 20.0


struct TextRainView: View {     
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            GeometryReader{ proxy in
                let size = proxy.size

                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(0...Int(size.width * 0.3 / rainSize), id: \.self) {_ in
                        
                        HStack{
                            MatrixRainCharacers(size: size)
                            Spacer()
                        }.frame(height: size.height, alignment: .center)
                            
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }.ignoresSafeArea()
            .statusBar(hidden: true)
            .background(.black)
    }
}
struct MatrixRainCharacers: View {
    @State private var startAnimation: Bool = false
    @State var quote = ""
    @State private var textSize = Double(.random(in: 10...40))

    let delayDuration = Double(.random(in: 0...2))
    
    let size: CGSize    
                       
    var body: some View {
        
        let randomHeight: CGFloat = .random(in: ((size.height / 2)...size.height))
        
        VStack{
            
            ForEach(0..<quote.count, id: \.self) {index in
                let character = Array(quote)[index]
                
                Text(String(character))
                    .font(.system(size: textSize, design: .rounded))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .scaledToFill()
            }
        }
        .mask(alignment: .top) {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(LinearGradient(colors: [
                    .clear,
                    .black.opacity(0.1),
                    .black.opacity(0.4),
                    .black.opacity(0.7),
                    .black
                ], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
                .frame(height: (size.height / 3))
                .frame(minWidth: textSize)
                .offset(y: startAnimation ? size.height : -randomHeight)
        }
        .onAppear{
            quote = Array(quotes)[Int.random(in: 0..<quotes.count)]
            withAnimation(
                .linear(duration: 18)
                .delay(delayDuration)
                .repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
                    startAnimation = true
                }
        }
        .onReceive(Timer.publish(every: (delayDuration + 18), on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()) { _ in
            textSize = Double(.random(in: 10...40))
            quote = Array(quotes)[Int.random(in: 0..<quotes.count)]
        }
    }
}


var quotes = ["THESE WOUNDS THEY WILL NOT HEAL", "JUST ONE MORE STEP CLOSER TO THE EDGE", "I AM ABOUT TO BREAK", "I NEED A LITTLE ROOM TO BREATHE", "RUN AWAY FROM EVERYTHING", "WHAT IS WRONG WITH ME?", "I GET LOST IN THE NOTHINGNESS INSIDE OF ME", "INSIDE OF ME...", "JUST STUCK HOLLOW AND ALONE", "THE FAULT IS MY OWN", "I WANNA FIND SOMEWHERE I BELONG", "I AM TIRED OF EVERYTHING", "I HAVE BECOME SO NUMB", "I CANT FEEL ANYTHING", "STUCK IN MY HEAD AGAIN...", "THERE IS NO ESCAPE", "IM MY OWN WORST ENEMY", "I'VE GIVEN UP!!!", "IM SICK OF THESE FEELINGS","WHAT THE HELL IS WRONG WITH ME????", "PUT ME OUT OF MY MISERY", "IM SUFFOCATING!", "SOMETIMES BEGINNING ARENT SO SIMPLE", "SOMETIMES GOODBYE IS THE ONLY WAY", "GOODBYE...", "IM HANGING OFF THE EDGE", "NOBODY CAN SAVE ME NOW", "BEEN SEARCHING FOR WHATS BEEN MISSING RIGHT HERE", "IM SUFFERING ENOUGH", "WHY ME? WHY? WHY? WHY? WHY?", "WHAT DID I DO WRONG?", "I DONT WANNA LIVE LIKE THIS ANYMORE", "I DONT FEEL GOOD", "HELP...", "IM TIRED OF EVERYTHING", "I DONT WANNA LIVE ANYMORE", "ILL NEVER ESCAPE THIS MADNESS", "THIS IS HELL!", "SO HOPELESS...", "WHAT CAN I DO...", "IM HELPLESS", "IT IS ALL MY FAULTS", "THE ONLY WAY IS..."]

    

struct TextRain_Preview: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TextRainView()
    }
}
```

I already set the time interval equal to animation duration plus delay time but somehow, after few refresh of the view with new quote, it won't sync anymore. That makes the quote change in the middle of the animation and makes the rain looks very weird.

Comment: while watching the animation quite a while without having a deeper look into the code it seems like the timer is performing a tick before the animation is done. Did you take into account that longer quotes need a longer animation than shorter?

Comment: @Carsten yes, I did notice that. Actually, I've just found out that I should had set `self.startAnimation.toggle()` instead of `startAnimation = true`. That's why the animation behaved so weird.